# WSREP detected deadlock/conflict while copying data from one table to another one

Tags: mysql

I'm stamped with the error I keep getting on the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO database1.table1
SELECT * FROM database2.table2;
```

table2 - InnoDB table, table 1 - MyISAM table.

The error looks like this:

> "SQL error (1213): WSREP detected deadlock/conflict and aborted the
>   transaction. Try restarting the transaction */"

I could workaround it by adding a limit of 500,000 records on select and performing this query part by part; but after 2,000,000 records are copied, the deadlock appear again, even if I reduce the limit per query to 5,000 records.

Which database settings may be responsible for this?

Comment: do you use Galera DB?

Comment: Did you find solution? On my server, after migrating database from Percona Server 5.5 (single server) to Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.7 (two nodes) this error start to occur, also in SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

Percona, MySQL 1.7.
Our administrator updated it to 1.7 a few weeks ago; before then this error didn't use to appear.

Comment: MySQL 1.7!? Do you mean **5.7**?